# How can I run asyncio in different classes simultaneously

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

How can I run asyncio in different classes simultaneously? For example, I have first class, where I have method async def main(). I have second class, where method display_info, which must always print some text. And I have third class, where I want to run async method in first class and not async method in second class.

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

class FirstClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    async def main(self):
        global loop
        print("Hello")

        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(20, loop=loop)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main())



class SecondClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def display_info(self):
        while True:
            print('People')

class Thirdclass():
    f_class = FirstClass()
    s_class = SecondClass()
    threads = list()
    th1 = Thread(target=s_class.display_info(self))
    th2 = Thread(target=f_class.main(self))
    threads.append(th1)
    threads.append(th2)
    th1.start()
    th2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Asyncio event loop typically is launched first, and everything else runs under its control.

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def first():
    while True:
        print("Hello")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

def second():
    while True:
        print('People')
        time.sleep(2)

async def main():
    # create classes and call methods here
    await asyncio.gather( # waits for both of the arguments to return
        asyncio.create_task(first()), # shedules first to run independently under asyncio
        asyncio.to_thread(second), # runs second in thread
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

You don't need to pass around the asyncio loop everywhere, it's inferred from the context. Mixing threads and async functions should be done under asyncio's control via `asyncio.to_thread`, however, the fact that you're mixing async and blocking code is itself an issue, and you should consider how to get rid of your blocking code.

Comment: Thanks. But it was a simple example. I have another more difficult code for me and there is a loop, which I can't remove. And I need to run few threads in different .py files. Here is a code, that I need to run from another py file: [code](https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-futures-python-sdk) There is Websockets

Comment: That library also uses asyncio, so you can just  `asyncio.create_task(call_to_that_lib())` to launch that loop

Comment: I try, but in my case one method is executed and the second one doesn't want to. Help me please to correctly implement asyncio.create_task(call_to_that_lib()) there

Comment: sorry, this is q&a site, working for free is a bit too much.

Comment: I knew theoretically that it was possible to do this through create_task. That's why I asked for help here.